# Verificar se uma variavel é numerica ou string

Tags: c++

Boa tarde,
Existe alguma função no C++ que verifica se a variável é uma string ou numerica?

Um exemplo:
Em PHP utilizo is_string(variavel)
ou is_numeric(variavel).

Comment: Não sei se existe uma função nativa. Mas há implementações como essa aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4654718/3293600

Comment: Você quer verificar se o tipo da variável mesmo, dentro de, por exemplo, uma função template, ou você tem uma string e quer validar se o conteúdo dela é número?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se vc está usando GCC pode usar o typeof. Ele retorna uma string com o tipo da variável. Ex.:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << typeof(int&) << '\n'; // int
```

Vc também pode usar o type ID. Assim:

```
#include <typeinfo>

// …
std::cout << typeid(a).name() << '\n';
```

Tem essa questão [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986418/typeid-versus-typeof-in-c) no Stackoverflow em inglês que explica a diferença entre os 2.